# How to keep Access from login in and out on every query?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010, linked-tables

I inherited an Access app and the data is in Linked tables.  The actual data is on a SQL Server box.  One thing I noticed in the SQL Profiler is that Access connects and disconnects on every query.

I am a noob in Access, but I am guessing one way to improve performance is to just have a persistent connection.

Is there a way to do this in this app?  Or is it not that simple?

Answer (score 1):

You never want to have a persistent connection. You always want to connect, get the data, and disconnect. Otherwise, there is un-necessary overhead on the database server. Everything is working in the best way as-is. SQL Server uses Connection Pooling for improved connectivity performance.